# Move files from client to server using webservice

Tags: c#

I have a windows application in my client system and a web service hosted in server. I want to transfer an image file (scanned image) from client's windows form application to a folder in server having web service. Can anyone help me?Please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `MemoryStream` to transfer files.

```
         try
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fs);
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path + 
                fileName,  FileMode.Create);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
                memoryStream.Close();
                fileStream.Close();
                fileStream = null;
                memoryStream = null;
                return "File has already uploaded successfully&#12290;";
           }
        catch (Exception ex)
           {
                return ex.Message;
           }
```

find a complete example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29273/Transfer-files-using-Web-Services)

Answer (score 0):

You could set-up an FTP server and copy the files programmatically via FTP. An example would be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx)